# DataTable access C#

Tags: c#, .net

Hey everyone I have the following code

```
Console.WriteLine("y: {0}", liveData.Tables["Players"].Rows.Count); //Shows full table

        DataRow[] foundRows;
        foundRows = liveData.Tables["Players"].Select("FName like 'Marc'");

        foreach (DataRow dr in foundRows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Index is " + dr.Table.Rows.IndexOf(dr));
        }
```

Now when i return my index of the row at variable dr that shows correctly

What i want to do is where it states Fname and Marc i want to pass those as variables and not manually input the string, is this possible?

Example, sometimes i may need to search Lname and whatever that is or a different first name?

Thank you for looking a bit stuck but again probably a simple answer :)

Comment: What's wrong with building your own string? You should really learn the basics: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228362(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you wish to have the query select a name from FName that resembles an input from an user (in this case 'Marc').

If thats the case, your best bet is to have something ask for the input beforehand and assign that value into a variable from a textbox for example.

```
String Queryname = TextBox1.Text

Console.WriteLine("y: {0}", liveData.Tables["Players"].Rows.Count); //Shows full table

    DataRow[] foundRows;
    foundRows = liveData.Tables["Players"].Select("FName like " + Queryname);

    foreach (DataRow dr in foundRows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Index is " + dr.Table.Rows.IndexOf(dr));
    }
```

Forgive me if I did not get your question. Let me know if that works and if not, try clarifying with an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
string SelectQuery=//create query based on user input
foundRows = liveData.Tables["Players"].Select(SelectQuery);
```

For example if user wants to search based on Last Name, then Lname+ like + search term.You need to map the search attribute with column names.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just build the string with variables?: `.Select(param+" like '"+value+"'")`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function

```
public DataRow[] MySelect(string column, string name)
{
    return liveData.Tables["Players"].Select(string.Format("{0} LIKE '{1}'", column, name));
}
```

And then use it like this

```
foundRows = MySelect("LName", "John");
```